# Itertools groupby with lambda function, group sublists of a list together if they have matching values at indices 0 and 1

Tags: python, performance, group-by, python-itertools

I have a list of lists like this:

```
data = [['a', 'b', 2000, 100], ['a', 'b', 4000, 500], ['c', 'd', 500, 8000], ['c', 'd', 60, 8000], ['c', 'd', 70, 1000], ['a', 'd', 2000, 100], ['a', 'd', 1000, 100]]
```

and I want to group them together if they have the same first two values. Output would be:

```
data = [(['a', 'b', 2000, 100], ['a', 'b', 4000, 500]), (['c', 'd', 500, 8000], ['c', 'd', 60, 8000], ['c', 'd', 70, 1000]), (['a', 'd', 2000, 100], ['a', 'd', 1000, 100])]
```

The sublists with the same first two values are always adjacent to each other in list, but they vary in the number of how many I need to group.

I tried this:

```
from itertools import groupby
data = [['a', 'b', 2000, 100], ['a', 'b', 4000, 500], ['c', 'd', 500, 8000], ['c', 'd', 60, 8000], ['c', 'd', 70, 1000], ['a', 'd', 2000, 100], ['a', 'd', 1000, 100]]
output = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(data, lambda x:x[0])]

new_data = []
for l in output:
    new_output = [tuple(group) for key, group in groupby(l, lambda x:x[1])]
    for grouped_sub in new_output:
        new_data.append(grouped_sub)

print(new_data)
```

and got the output:

```
[(['a', 'b', 2000, 100], ['a', 'b', 4000, 500]), (['c', 'd', 500, 8000], ['c', 'd', 60, 8000], ['c', 'd', 70, 1000]), (['a', 'd', 2000, 100], ['a', 'd', 1000, 100])]
```

Which is exactly what I was looking for. However, my list of lists is `len(data) = 1000000` and I know this could be much more efficient if I could skip the for loops entirely and somehow get the `groupby` `lambda` to consider both `x[0]` and `x[1]` when grouping.. but I do not really understand how `lambda` functions in `groupby` work all too well yet.

Comment: @itay I need to keep in the `csv` module because I am going to be iterating over the groups and iterating over columns in `pandas` is not a good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just group by first 2 items directly:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [['a', 'b', 2000, 100], ['a', 'b', 4000, 500], ['c', 'd', 500, 8000], ['c', 'd', 60, 8000], ['c', 'd', 70, 1000], ['a', 'd', 2000, 100], ['a', 'd', 1000, 100]]
res = [tuple(g) for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[:2])]
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[(['a', 'b', 2000, 100], ['a', 'b', 4000, 500]), (['c', 'd', 500, 8000], ['c', 'd', 60, 8000], ['c', 'd', 70, 1000]), (['a', 'd', 2000, 100], ['a', 'd', 1000, 100])]
```

Comment: @AnnaNevison, with slice `x[:2]` - `0` is implied as a starting index by default. By the way, my approach does not casting to tuple `tuple(...)` twice

Answer (score 6):

Modify the key lambda to return a tuple containing both elements:

```
groupby(data, lambda x: tuple(x[0:2]))
```

i.e. can be done in a single for-loop / list comprehension:

```
>>> [tuple(group) for key, group in groupby(data, lambda x: tuple(x[0:2]))]
[(['a', 'b', 2000, 100], ['a', 'b', 4000, 500]), 
 (['c', 'd', 500, 8000], ['c', 'd', 60, 8000], ['c', 'd', 70, 1000]), 
 (['a', 'd', 2000, 100], ['a', 'd', 1000, 100])]
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is right and you and the other answer commented at the same time with the same thing, but I am going to accept the other one as the answer just because it contains the full code and you don't need to technically start the slice at 0. (Also, yours has 5 upvotes so if I accept his he gets almost the same amount of points as you). But i appreciate the help so much! Thank you!

Comment: @AnnaNevison, you have a good sense of fairness and rationalism. I rarely seen that here on SO. ) Good one